# Cannot install MongoDB on Beaglebone Green

Tags: mongodb, debian, cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

The installation of **MongoDB** is still unsuccessful on the **BeagleBone Green** card.

More information about this BBG:

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 22 01:16:12 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Even I tried to follow this *tutorial* : https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ as below :

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.jgT79mhjhQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
gpg: key 58712A2291FA4AD5: "MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 main
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/{+package-branch+} main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-{+version+}.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/{+package-branch+} main
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                     
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease                                  
Hit:5 http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian stretch InRelease                               
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                       
Get:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 Release [2393 B]
Get:8 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 Release.gpg [801 B]
Fetched 97.5 kB in 5s (17.8 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.4 mongodb-org-server=3.6.4 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.4 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.4 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-shell
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-mongos
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: mongodb-org
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: mongodb-org-server
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: mongodb-org-shell
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: mongodb-org-mongos
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: mongodb-org-tools
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>
```

but the problem is still the same.

How can I fix this issue please?

Comment: The answer to why it failed is right there ```'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ARMv7-HF package offered by that repository.

The easiest option is to go with the Debian package:

`sudo apt install mongodb`

This will yield version 3.2.11 as indicated here: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mongodb

The more complicated option is to build it from source. This will potentially take a very long time if you do it directly on the BBB!

A rough guess at steps would be:

- This pulls in build dependencies for the debian mongodb, which may be sufficient, but at least should provide a decent base:
  `sudo apt build-dep mongo`
- [Download source code](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) - as of the time of me writing this it would be:
  `wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r3.6.5.tar.gz`
- Unpack: `tar -xvzf mongodb-src-r3.6.5.tar.gz`
- Change directory into source: `cd mongodb-src-r3.6.5`
- Build debian package from source: `dpkg-buildpackage -b`
- Install build results: `dpkg -i ../mongodb-org-bla-foo.deb`

The build step might possibly fail for a variety of reasons, e.g. unresolved dependencies. Please make sure to download the **latest** version to avoid exposing yourself to security issues and stability problems, the above mentioned URL is just an example and only valid at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply@TBR. When I try `sudo apt build-dep mongo` , I get : 
`Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: I'd recommend to give the official Debian package a try. 3.2.11 is not *that* old.

Comment: If you **really** feel you must have the latest, then follow the advice that the error message gives you: add URIs to source package repositories. (this is also well explained in many places discussing Debian)